# Confused about the texture unit value of texture sampler

Tags: opengl

I'm learning openGL texture from [leanrnOpenGL : Textures](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures)

I can distinguish between `glGetUniformLocation` and "texture unit.

- `glGetUniformLocation` :  an integer that represents the location of a specific uniform variable within a program object.
- texture unit : the location of a texture is known as a texture unit.

The pages has the following sentences:

```
We also have to tell OpenGL to which texture unit each shader sampler belongs to 
by setting each sampler using `glUniform1i`.
```

The corresponding code is as follows :

```
ourShader.use(); 
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "texture1"), 0); // set it manually
ourShader.setInt("texture2", 1); // or with shader class
```

I made some wrong changes as follows :

- assigned the texture unit value of `texture1` to  3, and `texture2` to 4.

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "texture1"), 3);
ourShader.setInt("texture2", 4);
```

The program can be executed, but show a COMPLETELY PURE black texture(or nothing?)

[image]

---

Does the value of texture unit have to start from  0 ? and why?

Why assigning 3 or 4 cause a wrong effect ?

Comment: The binding point between the texture object and the sampler uniform is the texture unit. You have to bid the texture to a texture unit ([`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml))

Comment: @Rabbid76 The sample code invokes `glActiveTexture`  with `GL_TEXTURE0` and `GL_TEXTURE1` together. But the value of `GL_TEXTURE0`(or `GL_TEXTURE1` ) is NOT equal to `0` (or `1`). This is also the question that confused me.

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE0` and `GL_TEXTURE1` are enumeration constants and correspond to the texture units 0 and 1.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh~~, I got it. I'm lucky to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under the guidance of @Rabbid76， I got the answer.

In the original text of [learnOpenGL : Texture](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures), there is a sentence that caused my confusion:

```
This location of a texture is more commonly known as a texture unit.
```

@Rabbid76 correct me:

```
The binding point between the texture object and the sampler uniform is the `texture unit`.
```

---

Does the value of texture unit have to start from 0 ?
A: No.
We can specify it by 0~15 at least.

```
OpenGL should have a at least a minimum of 16 texture units for you to use
which you can activate using GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE15.
```

Corresponding, when drawing,
invoke `glActiveTexture` by specify `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE15`.

---

The following is the correct code aftet my correction:

```
    // set `3` `4` as texture unit value
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "texture1"), 3);
    ourShader.setInt("texture2", 4);



    // bind textures on corresponding texture units
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);          // replace GL_TEXTURE0 with GL_TEXTURE3
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);          // replace GL_TEXTURE1 with GL_TEXTURE4
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

The code run normally and show the correct overlay effect(no longer a black view).